# Create condition from SqlDataReader's value then add into datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I make a condition from an object and add to datagridview?

This is my code..

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

Connection.sqlConnection.Close();
Connection.Connector(server, database, user, password);
Connection.sqlCommand.Connection = Connection.sqlConnection;
Connection.sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;            
Connection.sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ID,KOSAT,KETERANGAN,DELETEFLAG FROM KOSAT";

SqlDataReader kosatList = Connection.sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (kosatList.Read())
{    
    // this....................
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(kosatList["ID"], kosatList["KOSAT"], kosatList["KETERANGAN"], kosatList["DELETEFLAG"]);
    // until this................
}

Console.WriteLine("aaa = "+list);
Connection.sqlConnection.Close();

dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;
```

According to my code... I want create a condition from `kosatList["DELETEFLAG"]` like this..

```
string yesORno;

if(kosatList["DELETEFLAG"].Equals("Y"))
{
   yesORno = "YES";
}
else if(kosatList["DELETEFLAG"].Equals("N"))
{
   yesORno = "NO";
}
```

Then how can I add `yesORno` to row datagridview1?

I tried like this..

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(kosatList["ID"], kosatList["KOSAT"], kosatList["KETERANGAN"], yesORno);
```

but I got error because `Rows.Add()` ==> must be `Object`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just change the query to bring in the data you want so you don't have to manipulate it:

```
SELECT ID,KOSAT,KETERANGAN, 
CASE DELETEFLAG 
   WHEN 'Y' THEN 'YES'
   WHEN 'N' THEN 'NO'
   ELSE '<your choice>'
END AS DELETEFLAG
FROM KOSAT
```